# out of range in objectAtIndex objective c

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

The count of `children_` (`CCArray`) outputs 15 and I'm receiving error:

```
'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'index out of range in objectAtIndex(14), index 15'

for (NSInteger i=[children_ count]-1; i>=0; i++) {

        CCNode *c = [children_ objectAtIndex:i];

        if ([c isKindOfClass:[CCLabelTTF class]]) {
            [c removeFromParentAndCleanup:YES];
        }
    }
```

How would I solve this? Trying to remove all the labels in order to change their string value.
On my CCLayer I have have also some CCMenuItemLabel and CCMenuItemLabelAndSprite...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you want to iterate backwards through the collection class, so you need to perform `i--` to modify the index variable:

```
for (NSInteger i=[children_ count]-1; i>=0; i--) {

    CCNode *c = [children_ objectAtIndex:i];

    if ([c isKindOfClass:[CCLabelTTF class]]) {
        [c removeFromParentAndCleanup:YES];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

you should use [fast enumerating](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/objectivec/Chapters/ocFastEnumeration.html) if possible:

```
for (id obj in [childres_ reverseObjectEnumerator]){
    if ([obj isKindOfClass:[CCLabelTTF class]]) {
        [obj removeFromParentAndCleanup:YES];
    }
}
```

or with the [block syntax](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Collections/Articles/Enumerators.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000135-BBCFABCB)

```
[children_ enumerateObjectsWithOptions:NSEnumerationReverse usingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop){
    if ([obj isKindOfClass:[CCLabelTTF class]]) {
        [obj removeFromParentAndCleanup:YES];
        stop= YES;
    };
}];
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you are initializing your for loop counter with count-1 and incrementing, so the first value of i would be 14 , and the next one 15 (out of range)

Try this :

```
for (NSInteger i=0; i<[children_ count]; i++) {
}
```